# localizable.strings editor for translators

Tags: xcode, localization, translation, localizable.strings

Does anyone know any good and easy to use editor for translating localizable.strings files generated from xCode ?

The program will be used by total non technical people, so it should be very easy to use and ensure that no errors are made during the translation process that could lead to a non working file (for example, a missing semicolon at the end of the string, or an unescaped double quote).

I'm trying to find a really easy to use tool for our translators and I can't find one :-(
The only thing I found is the [Localization Suite](http://www.loc-suite.org/), but I think this is too complicated to use by people that are not that techy...

Suggestions ?

I'm editing to say that Clafou's answer would have been the correct one IF Gengo supported the comments in the localizable strings file. But it is omitting it and this is not good. I really hope there is something better as a solution out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an online tool for this called Gengo String: http://gengo.com/string/about/

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it looks good, but have you used it? It doesn't seem to be able to show my comments from the localizable.strings, which are crucial for some translation strings...

Comment: No I haven't tried it, that's a pity about those comments. If there an annotation feature you can use as a backup? Looks like they are working on a new version, maybe they'll fix that. In the past I used Amanuens, a very similar tool where you could manually annotate strings to guide the translator, but this tool has since been taken offline (I assume because it lost out to Gengo, which seems better established)

Comment: Note that generally speaking, the need for a comment should be an exception rather than the norm. If every single string has a comment, the translator might just ignore them all (translators aren't paid much per word and don't spend a long time on each entry). So if only a few strings require an explanation, you could always provide this information separately in an email or some other document.

Comment: Well, we have in house translators, so we use them. But we are trying to find an easy way for them to work with. Your solution is at the moment the best and I contacted the Gengo support to ask if they plan on adding support for comments, but it raises problems. Our translators already asked me for details for a couple of strings, because my comments that would have answered their questions where removed...

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy to do some file conversion you could use [Pootle](http://pootle.translatehouse.org/) to host you own online translation, that eliminates most of the techie overhead and the need to install software.

The conversion would be using [prop2po](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/toolkit/prop2po) to convert your strings files to PO files that Pootle can directly use.  But the trade-off for non-techie users can be worth it.

*Disclaimer* : I code on Pootle.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that I have then to convert back to the localizable.strings file format after the translators are done ?

Comment: Yes it does.  But it also puts the strings into PO which allows translators to use a larger array of localisation editing tools.

Answer (score 1):

[POEditor](https://poeditor.com) has a pretty straightforward interface that's suitable for collaborative translation. It supports .strings files and comments.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11330604)

Comment: I don't see how my answer is any different in form from the others.

Comment: Your answer got flagged for review, while the others may not have. But thanks for pointing them out. Even the question isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Weblate](https://weblate.org/), which supports strings file without any conversion, but relies on Git, so if you are not using it, it would also require some additional setup.

There are also some third party services you can use, I know at least https://www.transifex.com/ and https://crowdin.com/ who do support Apple strings, check their conditions for pricing (AFAIK they offer free plans for free software).